# What HTML Editor Should I Use?

Tags: php, html, css, ide, html-editor

I'm a college student and have taken several web development and web design courses.  Over the last few years I have used the following:

PHPStorm
Visual Studio Code
Notepad++
SublimeText3
Atom

Amongst all of those, I don't really have a preference.  I lean towards Jetbrains since as a student I get full access via student license.  But those other editors/IDE's work fine too.  If you were in my shoes which would you opt to use more frequently?

Comment: This question is either too broad, opinion based or requires discussion and so is not suitable for Stack Overflow. If you have a specific, answerable, programming issue, please provide full details.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a front-end developer, I mostly use VScode it's powerful with lots of features. You can customize it as per your needs.
It has a huge library of extensions which are really handy.

I think VScode is best for web developers. Whatsoever.